# Splitting Loop Between Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

My code gets open ports from the given host.
This process is very time consuming

Code :

```
for(int port=0;port<11;port++)
{
    string statusTCP = "Open";
    using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
    {
         try{ tcp.Connect("127.0.0.1",port);
         }catch { statusTCP="Close";}
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Port " + port + " : " + statusTCP);
}
```

This process takes **11s** for me !
This is very long if i check 100 or 1000 ports...

Any **Good** & **Fast** way to do this ?

Comment: Parallel.for should be using threads and asynchronous where possible

Comment: You don't need multithreading *at all*. You can use the asynchronous [ConnectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method to connect asynchronously - ie using the underlying IO completion port mechanisms without blocking a thread.

Comment: You should also consider adding a timeout to the sockets. By default, it should be 1 second which is way too long when scanning localhost. To do so, you can use:
`tcpClient.ConnectAsync().Wait(timeout);`

Comment: @Pimich *Wait* *blocks*. This would waste whatever was gained by using `ConnectAsync`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need multiple threads to connect to multiple ports. You can use [ConnectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync(v=vs.110).aspx) to connect *asynchronously*. Windows uses asynchronous IO through completion ports from the NT days.

This means that no threads are blocked, the OS notifies the original thread when an IO request completes. In fact, blocking is *simulated* to make synchronous programming easier.

You can create a single method that connects to a single port and reports a message when finished. Writing to the console *blocks* though, so I'll use the [IProgress< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to report progress:

```
public async Task ConnectToPortAsync(string host,int port,IProgress<string> progress)
{
    using(var client=new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(host,port).ConfigureAwait(false);
            progress.Report($"Port: {port} Open");
            //Do some more work
        }
        catch 
        {
            progress.Report($"Port {port} Closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a list of ports:

```
var ports=new[]{80,8080,...};
```

or

```
var ports=Enumerable.Range(0,11);
```

You can call multiple ports simultaneously like this:

```
var host="127.0.0.1";
var progress=new Progress<string>(msg=>Console.WriteLine(msg););

var allTasks= ports.Select(port=>ConnectToPortAsync(host,port,progress));

await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

This code will use the main thread up until the first `await`. This means that all `TcpClient` instances will be created using the main thread. After that though, the code will execute asynchronously, using a thread from the IO Completion thread pool whenever necessary.

Reporting is performed by the main thread by the [Progress< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) object, so the background threads don't block waiting to write to the console.

Finally, once `await` returns, execution continues on the original synchronization context. For a desktop application (WPF, Winforms) that would be the main thread. That's OK if you want to update the UI after an asynchronous operation, but can cause blocking if you want to perform more work in the background. By using `ConfigureAwait(false)` we instruct the runtime to keep working on the background thread

*Further improvements :*

You can add a timeout in case a connection takes too long, by using [Task.Delay()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Task.WhenAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194796(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
var connectionTask=client.ConnectAsync(host,port);
var timeout=Task.Delay(1000);
var completed=await Task.WhenAny(connectionTask,timeout);
if(completed==connectionTask)
{ 
    progress.Report($"Port {port} Open");
}
else
{
    progress.Report($"Port {port} Timeout");
}
```

Comment: Thank you For Your Answer , but i have 2 errors with your method 
`1. IProgress<T> : The Type Or Namespace Name 'T' Could Not be Found`

`2. progress.Report(...) : Cannot Convert From String To T`

Comment: @alix54 oops, forgot to use `IProgress<string>` there

Comment: It should be noted that there's a big difference in using a thread (do things at the same time wasting CPU) and using a Task (can avoid CPU time on things that do not use CPU time). So a Thread does things at the same time, while a Task will give a result somewhere in the future. Await only handles the delay.

Comment: Not quite. Tasks use threads. Using raw threads, requires *creating* them which is expensive. A Task will probably start executing faster because it will use a ThreadPool thread. The same happens if you use `ThreadpoolThread.QueueWorkItem`. A Threadpool can grow to thousands of threads. Besides, with IO, it's not the *thread* that does the blocking work. If you used the Win32 API, you'd use a function with a callback back to the original thread to perform async IO

Comment: Only Task.Run can move CPU bound work to a background thread. async and await don't create additional threads, because a async method doesn't run on its own thread. The async method runs in the current synchronization context. That means it's using time on the current thread only when the method is active. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: @user743414 didn't say otherwise. The whole point is that IO is async. Blocking is an emulation. If you use async, you don't need any threads. That *task* is a placeholder for the async operation. Even if you used `Connect`, the OS would *still* perform the same IO. Would it clear things up if I used `BeginConnect`? `BeginConnect` won't start later compared to a blocking call.

Comment: Worked Perfectly , Thankyou Sir

Answer (score 3):

If what you're asking is how to run multiple lookups in parallel, take a look at the `Parallel` class.

```
Parallel.For(0, 11, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, (port) =>
{
    string statusTCP = "Open";
    using (TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            tcp.Connect("127.0.0.1", port);
        }
        catch { statusTCP = "Close"; }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Port " + port + " : " + statusTCP);
});
```

Note in the first few method parameters where I specify to go from 0-10 (because 11 is exclusive) and execute 5 lookups in parallel with the `ParallelOptions` class.

Comment: @alix54 Parallel.For won't hang the program. The main thread is one of the 5 threads used. Did you wait for all connections to complete? Did you try debugging?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used this method in `BackGroundWorker` , I don't think the main method is used...

Comment: @alix54 what's the point of using BGW when you have TPL and Parallel.For? If you wanted the loop to run in the background, surround it with Task.Run. BGW is obsolete, as all of its functionality is provided by the TPL (including progress reporting).

Comment: @alix54 - BackgroundWorker and Console.WriteLine() don't make much sense together. So you asked a bad question and still got  a good answer. Solve the integration issues by yourself.

Comment: @alix54 anyway, did you try *pausing* the debugger and checking the Parallel Stacks window? This will show you which threads are running or not

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I paused , Debugger Break is on `Parallel.For` and in events shows : `Debugger Break - 133.84s - [7992]<No Name>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Also there is a yellow arrow next to `WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne` in `Thread1` in Parallel Stacks window And `Thread1` & `Thread5` have a blue border

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But why this never ends ??

Comment: @alix54 what does each call stack show? Without the call stacks one can only guess. One guess is that services behind the ports don't respond. You didn't provide a timeout so the `Connect` operation won't complete. If that's the case, you'll see that the call stack contains the `TcpClient.Connect` call at some point